# Grails 2.3.0 Restful Service Runtime Exception

Tags: grails, java-7

I´m currently running Grails 2.3.0 and Java jdk1.7.0_40 on a Windows 7 machine, no IDE. I wanted to see how the new Rest functionality looks like. So I created the domain class as follows:

```
package fergara
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri='/Cars', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Car {

    String model

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The error I got when open the url:

URI
    /FergaraTest/Cars/1 Class
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
Message
    Cannot cast object 'fergara.CarController@12c43f7' with class 'fergara.CarController' to class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.CommonWebApi'

I feel that the Oracle´s Java SDK is the problem. To make the app run I have to pass "no-reloading" to the grails run-app command, otherwise I get an error saying that it could not start the VM and cannot open the springloaded-core-1.1.3.jar.

A have the Grails 2.3.0 installed on an Ubuntu 13.04 with OpenJDK6 and it is working good.

Hope someone can shed a light on this. Thank you.

Comment: Have the same issue, with Grails 2.3.1.  Oracle Java SDK 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: The problem was solved. I installed the Grails 2.3.1 in c:\Grails\Grails-2.3.1. Did not touch Java (jdk1.7.0_40) installation. Remember not to install Grails in a path like "C:\Program Files (x86)". I´ve read that it has some issues with the spaces and access to system folders.